# CDF and the floor!

Tags: calculus

I am working with Cumulative Distribution Function and trying to understand how to approach a few questions.

Problem:
$F(x)= \left\{ \begin{array} \\ k-\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}, x\ge 1,\\ 0, x\lt 1,\end{array} \right.$ is a cummulative distibution function (cdf) for some fixed number k.

Find:

1. $k$,
2. $x_{min}$ (the smallest number with non-zero probability)
3. $P(X=4)$
4. $P(2\lt X\le5)$

QUESTION 1: Somehow I was able to understand that the answer is $1$.

QUESTION 2: I assumed that the smallest number that $x$ can be is $1$ because the statement clarifies that for $k-\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}$, $x\ge1$. But when I answered $1$ it was wrong.  What am I missing here?

QUESTION 3: When I enter in $4$ for $x$ it then becomes: $1-\frac{1}{4}$ since $\lfloor 4\rfloor$ should equal $4$. So reducing the equation I got $\frac{3}{4}$ and that was wrong.  What am I missing here?

QUESTION 4: Since I am not getting the above questions right I am not sure how to approach this.  I would have thought that I would replace $x$ with the values that are $X$ in $(2\lt X \le5)$ would be $\{3,4,5\}$.

Comment: First of all, thank you for writing your question in detail. May I know the whereabouts of this question? Is this from a textbook you are reading?

Comment: It is from an online course I am taking.

Comment: Please inspect the below answer and provide feedback. I think it does a good job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$k=1$ is right: It comes from the fact that $F(x) \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$.

$F(x)=0$ for $x <2$ since $[x]=1$ anf $F(x)=0$ if $1 \leq x <2$ Hence $x_{min} =2$.

$P(X=4)=P(X\leq 4) -P(X<4)=(1-\frac  1 4) -(1-\frac 1  3)$ since $F(x)=1-\frac 1  3$ in $(3,4)$. So $P(X=4)=\frac 1 {12}$ [$P(X<x)$ is the limit of $P(X \leq y) \equiv F(y)$ as $y $ increases to $x$].

For the last part use: $P(2<X \leq 5)=F(5)-F(2)$.

Comment: For your question 3 response I see that you have: $P(X=4)=P(X\leq 4) -P(X<4)$, but I don't understand why you have the $P(X\leq 4) -P(X<4)$ part.  why isn't it just $P(X\leq 4)$?

Comment: $X=4$ is not the same as $X \leq $ . Why do you say $P(X=4)=P(X \leq 4)$? You have to use that fact that $X=4$ iff $X \leq 4$ but it is not true that $X<4$. @Fototekt

Comment: For the last part when I try to reduce those $F(5)-F(2)$ I get: $F(5)=(1- \frac{1}{5})-(1-\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{20}$ and $F(2)=(1-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$.  So when I subtract them I end up with $\frac{1}{20}-\frac{1}{2}$ which is $-\frac{9}{20}$?

Comment: $F(5)-F(2)=(1-\frac 1 5)-(1-\frac 1  2)=\frac 3 {10}$ @Fototekt

Comment: @Fototekt To find $F(5)$ you just put $x=5$ in the given definition.

Comment: Thank you all for the help!  This was great to learn more about the Cumulative Distribution Function. I'm still a little fuzzy on the $X=4$ vs $X\le4$ part but that's ok.

Comment: That is the somewhat non-trivial part of the question. In general $P(X=x)=F(x)-\lim_{ y\to x, y <x} F(y)$ if $X$ is a random variable with distribution function $F$. @Fototekt